# IOS: pageViewController interface orientation

Tags: ios, iphone, uiviewcontroller, uipageviewcontroller, uiinterfaceorientation

I create it with code:

```
self.pageViewController = [[PageViewController alloc] initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal options:@{ UIPageViewControllerOptionInterPageSpacingKey : @30 }];
self.pageViewController.delegate = self;
self.pageViewController.dataSource = self;
self.pageViewController.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
self.currentMediaPlayerViewController = [self createMediaPlayerViewControllerWithMediaItem:self.mediaItems[self.pageIndex]];
NSArray *pageViewControllers = @[self.currentMediaPlayerViewController];
[self.pageViewController setViewControllers:pageViewControllers
                                  direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward
                                   animated:NO
                                 completion:nil];
[self addChildViewController:self.pageViewController];
[self.pageViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
[self.view addSubview:self.pageViewController.view];
```

I enable only landscape orientation in parentVC to pageViewController. But still can catch rotation.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

self.navigationController.delegate = self;

NSNumber *value = @(UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft);
NSString *keyOrientation = @"orientation";
if (![value isEqualToNumber:@((NSInteger)[[UIDevice currentDevice] valueForKey:keyOrientation])]) {
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:value forKey:@"orientation"];
}


- (NSUInteger)navigationControllerSupportedInterfaceOrientations: (UINavigationController *)navigationController
{
return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
```

How can I enable only landscape orientation in pageViewController?

Answer (score 0):

try to use this code

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    if (self.isLandscapeOK) {
        // for iPhone, you could also return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
    }
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```